# Improve MySql query left outer joins with subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, query-optimization

We are maintaining a history of Content. We want to get the updated entry of each content, with create Time and update Time should be of the first entry of the Content. The query contains multiple selects and where clauses with so many left joins. The dataset is very huge, thereby query is taking more than 60 seconds to execute. Kindly help in improving the same. Query:

```
select * from (select * from (

    SELECT c.*, initCMS.initcreatetime, initCMS.initupdatetime, user.name as partnerName, r.name as rightsName, r1.name as copyRightsName, a.name as agelimitName, ct.type as contenttypename, cat.name as categoryname, lang.name as languagename FROM ContentCMS c 

        left join ContentCategoryType ct on ct.id = c.contentType 
        left join User user on c.contentPartnerId = user.id 
        left join Category cat on cat.id = c.categoryId 
        left join Language lang on lang.id = c.languageCode 
        left join CopyRights r on c.rights = r.id 
        left join CopyRights r1 on c.copyrights = r1.id 
        left join Age a on c.ageLimit = a.id 
        left outer join (

            SELECT contentId, createTime as initcreatetime, updateTime as initupdatetime from ContentCMS cms where cms.deleted='0'

        ) as initCMS on initCMS.contentId = c.contentId WHERE c.deleted='0' order by c.id  DESC

) as temp group by contentId) as c where c.editedBy='0'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Please format your code reasonably--see the formatted post below the edit box. [mcve] please. Read an intro to query optimization--constraints, indexes & plans are critical, but you give no info.

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial eval and suggestion because your query seems non properly formed

This left join seems unuseful

```
    FROM ContentCMS c 
    ......
    left join (
        SELECT contentId
            , createTime as initcreatetime
            , updateTime as initupdatetime 
        from ContentCMS cms 
        where cms.deleted='0'
    ) as initCMS on initCMS.contentId = c.contentId
```

same table

the order by (without limit) in a subquery in join is unuseful   because join ordered values or unordered  value produce the same result

the group by  contentId is strange beacuse there aren't aggregation function and the sue of group by without aggregation function is deprecated  is sql 
and in the most recente version for mysql is not allowed (by deafult)  if you need  distinct value or just a rows  for each contentId you should use distinct or retrive the value in a not casual manner (the use of group by without aggregation function retrive casual value for not aggregated  column .

for a partial eval your query should be refactored as

```
SELECT c.*
          , c.initcreatetime
          , c.initupdatetime
          , user.name as partnerName
          , r.name as rightsName
          , r1.name as copyRightsName
          , a.name as agelimitName
          , ct.type as contenttypename
          , cat.name as categoryname
          , lang.name as languagename 
      FROM ContentCMS c 
      left join ContentCategoryType ct on ct.id = c.contentType 
      left join User user on c.contentPartnerId = user.id 
      left join Category cat on cat.id = c.categoryId 
      left join Language lang on lang.id = c.languageCode 
      left join CopyRights r on c.rights = r.id 
      left join CopyRights r1 on c.copyrights = r1.id 
      WHERE c.deleted='0' 
) as temp
```

for the rest you should expiclitally select the column you effectively need add proper aggregation function for the others

Also the nested  subquery just for improperly reduce the rows don't help performance ... you should also re-eval you data modelling and design.